# Multi Slide Representation

Tags: java

I have a project in which I am supposed to have a simple painting panel and I also have to make it possible for the user to have more than one drawing panel, like a multi slide representation.
So far, I finished the coding for 1 single panel which is an expansion of JPanel. Now, with two smiple JButtons on it(previous and next), I need to be able to open a new clean panel and I also need to be able to go back to the previous one which includes my last drawings.
I'm kinda stuck here and need some idea about how to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) for the slides.  It has `next()` / `previous()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinkedList to represent your slides, each element of the linkedList could be the JPanel. To navigate I think it's easier to use a [ListIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) (you can access it with the method LinkedList.listIterator()), so when your user press the forward button your could would look like:

```
void btnForwardPressed(){
    if(!this.iter.hasNext()) System.out.println("No slides forward");
    else this.currentSlide = this.iter.next();
}
```

And for the back button you would have something like this:

```
void btnBackPressed(){
    if(!this.iter.hasPrevious()) System.out.println("No slides back");
    else this.currentSlide = this.iter.previous();
}
```

You could also control the back and forward buttons state by tracking the return of the methods `this.iter.hasPrevious()` and `this.iter.hasNext()`.